# Microsoft Solver Foundation multithreading in c#

Tags: solver

I have problem when using Microsoft Solver Foundation in my multithreading c# application:

I run two threads in the same time and on every thread I call function like this:

```
private void exampleFunction()
{
    SolverContext context;
    Model model;

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        context = SolverContext.GetContext();
        model = context.CreateModel();

        //adding decisions, constraints and goal to model

        Solution sol = context.Solve();
        string s = sol.Quality.ToString();//and here sometimes I get that sol is null!
        context.ClearModel();
    }
}
```

It looks like the context that I have in every thread is the same object, so when I invoke

```
context.ClearModel();
```

in thread1, then it's also clear in thread2 (even if problem in thread2 was not solved yet).

So the question is: is there any way to solve two models in the same time in MSF? Is it possible to declare two SolverContext which won't be same?